# Django South datamigration pre_save() uses model's __unicode__()

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south, autofield

My `Blog` model has `AutoSlugField` which uses `Blog.__unicode__()` method.

After data migration all `Blog` instances have slug set to `blog-object-<number>` instead of `<year>-<month>-<day>`. Seems like definition `Blog.__unicode__()` is ignored.

How could I correctly migrate `Blog` model?

modelfields.py:

```
class AutoSlugField(models.CharField):
    def pre_save(self, blog, *args, **kwargs):
        return slugify(unicode(blog))
```

models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Migration:

```
from south.v2 import DataMigration

class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        for blog in orm.Blog.objects.all():
            blog.title = blog.title.replace('django', 'Django')
            blog.save()
```

Comment: What's exactly happening? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Arpit Blog.__unicode__() definition is ignored during data migration. I don't know how to export it to the migration file, because AutoSlugField uses pre_save() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated to South 0.7.6 and used solution from the [South documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part4.html#simple-inheritance). Simply added `to_python()` and `get_prep_value()` methods to leave `slug` field as is.

```
class AutoSlugField(models.CharField):
    def pre_save(self, blog, *args, **kwargs):
        return slugify(unicode(blog))

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

South does nothing but just add column to your table and django has no role to play in it. So when you run migration, django model save method is not called hence no pre-save method gets called. South works on database only, i.e., you can provide attributes such as default value, nullable etc. which can be set at db level. To add slug to existing records in db, create util function which would slugify your field or write a data migration.

Comment: You are talking about schemamigration, but I use datamigration. During data migration I inport data to my Blog objects and call save() method and it brokes the slug fields.

Comment: Ah..you modified code since my last read, sorry, I didn't saw that..Can you provide your migration?

Comment: Sure, just added. As I said, problem is how to export Blog.__unicode__() to my migration.